# When using Racer for code completion in Vim, the .racertmp temp file is not removed

Tags: vim, rust

I am using racer and the racer vim plugin for code completion for developing using Rust.

Racer creates a temporary file called: `<your original file name>.rs.racertmp`

After I finish editing and save this temp file is still there and not removed.

Any ideas if this is a bug or a solution for it?

Comment: Looking through the code, there isn't a way (that I can see) for this to happen... Racer always does a `call delete(tmpfname)` at the end of completion.  I would advise adding debugging statements to the Racer plugin and watch what happens, assuming you're familiar with VimL.